# Tic Tac Toe in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe

The code works fine but the compMove() function isn't working as I intended. I want it to do the following:
1. If the user(X) has a winning move then block it.
2. If the computer has a winning move(O) then take it.

This is the link to the program:

[This is the hyperlink to the jsfiddle implementation of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/vokqj28v/1/)

Given below is the javascript part of the game.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0;

  function isAvailableField($this) {
    return !$this.attr('data-move');
  }

  function userMove($this, move) {
    $this.attr('data-move', move);
    $this.addClass(move);
  }

  function reset() {
    $('.move-x').removeClass('move-x');
    $('.move-o').removeClass('move-o');
    $('.grid td').attr('data-move', '');
    count = 0;
  }

  $('.grid td').click(function () {
    if (isAvailableField($(this))) {
      userMove($(this), 'move-x');
      count++;
      checkWin();
      compMove();
    }
  });

  function compMove(){
    if(isAvailableField('#field' + 1)&&($('#field'+2).attr('data-move') == $('#field' + 3).attr('data-move') || $('#field' + 5).attr('data-move') == $('#field' + 9).attr('data-move') || $('#field' + 4).attr('data-move')==$('#field' + 7).attr('data-move'))) {
      userMove('#field'+1,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+2)&&($('#field'+1).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+3).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+8).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+2,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+3)&&($('#field'+2).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+1).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+7).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+6).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+9).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+3,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+4)&&($('#field'+1).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+7).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+6).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+4,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+5)&&($('#field'+2).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+8).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+1).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+9).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+3).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+7).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+4).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+6).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+5,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+6)&&($('#field'+4).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+3).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+9).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+6,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+7)&&($('#field'+1).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+4).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+3).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+8).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+9).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+7,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+8)&&($('#field'+2).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+7).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+9).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+8,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else if(isAvailableField('#field'+9)&&($('#field'+1).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+5).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+3).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+6).attr('data-move')||$('#field'+7).attr('data-move')==$('#field'+8).attr('data-move'))){
      userMove('#field'+9,'move-o');
      count++;
      checkWin();
    }

    else{
      if(isAvailableField('#field'+5)){
        userMove('#field'+5,'data-move');
        count++;
        checkWin();
      }
      else if(isAvailableField('#field'+1)){
        userMove('#field'+1,'data-move');
        count++;
        checkWin();
      }
      else if(isAvailableField('#field'+9)){
        userMove('#field'+9,'data-move');
        count++;
        checkWin();
      }
      else if(isAvailableField('#field'+8)){
        userMove('#field'+8,'data-move');
        count++;
        checkWin();
      }
      else{
        userMove('#field'+4,'data-move');
        count++;
        checkWin();
      }
    }

  }

  var winconditions = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 5, 7],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 6, 9]
  ];

  function judgmentDay(move) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winconditions.length; i++) {
      var line = winconditions[i];
      var j = 0;
      for (; j < line.length; j++) {
        var num = line[j];
        if ($('#field' + num).attr('data-move') != move) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (j == line.length) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  function checkWin() {
    if (count < 5) {
      return;
    }
    if (judgmentDay('move-x')) {
      alert("X wins!");
      reset();
    } else if (judgmentDay('move-o')) {
      alert("O wins!");
      reset();
    } else if (count == 9) {
      alert("It's a draw!");
      reset();
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: $this.attr is not a function` when I try it. Did you look into that?

Comment: There should be a space between the ! and the $this.attr. I just checked it and now it is not an issue. Can you help me with the compMove function? If you execute the code in jsfiddle, you will see what the problem is. Some logical error probably.

Comment: You forgot the $ in the calls of isAvailableField. e.g. `isAvailableField('#field'+3)` should be `isAvailableField($('#field'+3))` otherwise you call .attr() on a string.

Comment: Oh crap! Thanks so much Peter :) That was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @Nimish The space doesn't matter (you get the same error in either case). What matters is that you're trying to use an undefined variable called `$this.attr`.

Comment: I made the changes but the problem persists. Status quo.

Comment: @Biffen the same thing works for this guy's code:                                               http://jsfiddle.net/z9axM/

Comment: @Nimish Yeah, because he calls `isAvailableField()` with a variable that *has* an `attr()` function.

Comment: The code is working however the compMove () function isn't operating as I intended it to. I want it to do the following: 1. If the user(X) has a winning move, then block it 2. If the computer(O) has a winning move, take it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use jquery elements as parameters for isAvailableField and userMove.
e.g.

```
isAvailableField('#field'+3)
```

must be

```
isAvailableField($('#field'+3))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ha4n3c27/ is a working example

Comment: the code is working however the compMove () function isn't operating as I intended it to. I want it to do the following: 1. If the user(X) has a winning move, then block it 2. If the computer(O) has a winning move, take it.